# How can I call a different method than run() from a Thread

Tags: java, multithreading

Let's say I have a `post()` and a `get()` method that I want to run from a different thread. Is it possible to do this with just one class that extends `Thread`, where those methods are not in the `run()` method?

I thought of this:

```
XYThread xy = new XYThread();
xy.start();
xy.post();
xy.get();
```

But in this case, would it still would be multithreading after the `run()` method is finished?

Comment: But that would mean I have to create two different classes for post and get if I want to call them seperately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the work *inside* the `run` method; and call whatever methods you wish to call.

However, `run` and *only* `run` is called "within" the thread. In the posted code both `post` and `get` are *not* executed within the context of the `xy` thread; but instead in the context of the current thread.

It is also possible to supply a Runnable to a thread, which once again has its `run` method invoked, such that the Thread does not need to be sub-classed. And yes, at some level this means creating different classes or otherwise embedding logic.

Comment: So there is really no easier way than creating two classes or trying somehow to embed logic in the run method for this example?

Comment: An anonymous (Runnable or Thread) class can be created, but that is as close as you're gonna get. Eg. `Thread xy = new Thread(new Runnable { public void run() { /* .. */ } })`.

Comment: @Marcel_marcel1991 It's generally odd for a thread to not be "unified" in what it does though. The `run` for any particular task (which is a concept Runnable's help to pull out) should be fairly distinct.

Answer (score 0):

Just call it from the `run()` method.